# Copying and pasting existing tables within word and continuing the numbering (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a VBA script that copies an entire word document (which has multiple tables and where the left most column has a numbered list) and pastes it at the end of the word document. The script then restarts the numbered list from '1' again.

My script works perfectly fine when I run it from within the word document that it is performing all the copying / pasting - however it does not work when I run it from a separate word document that iterates through a folder full of word documents.

Firstly, here is the script that actually works:

```
Sub CopyAndPasteEntireDocument()

    Dim TotalNumberOfTables As Integer

    ' save the total number of tables in this document
    TotalNumberOfTables = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

    ' Copy and paste the whole document (so it is duplicated)
    With Selection
        .WholeStory
        .Copy
        .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        .Paste
    End With
    
    ' Restart the numbering of the new tables (that were just pasted) from number 1
    ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1).StartAt = 1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(2, 1).Select
    
    ' this next line is where the document hangs
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
        
    ' Fix up the formatting of the first number in the new list (which is in the second row by copying the formatting info from the third row)
    ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(3, 1).Select
    Selection.CopyFormat
    ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(2, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteFormat
End Sub
```

When I modify the code to then iterate through a folder which contains multiple documents, everything works except for the line that is trying to restart the numbered list from '1'. Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyAndPasteEntireDocumentFromFolder()
    Dim TotalNumberOfTables As Integer  ' used to store the number of tables in the document before duplicating everything
    Dim FName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Set wrd = CreateObject("word.application")
    wrd.Visible = True
    
    ' open a dialog box allowing the user to select a folder containing the word documents
    FilePath = GetFolder
    
    ' Find all .docx files in our filepath
    FName = Dir(FilePath & "*.docx")
    
    ' open and edit each file in that folder
    Do While (FName <> "")
        With wrd
            ' Open the next document in the folder
            .Documents.Open (FilePath & FName)
            
            ' save the total number of tables in this document
            TotalNumberOfTables = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

            ' Copy and paste the whole document (so it is duplicated)
            With .Selection
                .WholeStory
                .Copy
                .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
                .Paste
            End With
            
            ' Restart the numbering of the new tables (that were just pasted) from number 1
            .ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1).StartAt = 1
            .ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(2, 1).Select
            
            ' this next line is where the document hangs
            .Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
                False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
                wdWord10ListBehavior
                
            ' Fix up the formatting of the first number in the new list (which is in the second row by copying the formatting info from the third row)
            .ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(3, 1).Select
            .Selection.CopyFormat
            .ActiveDocument.Tables(TotalNumberOfTables + 1).Cell(2, 1).Select
            .Selection.PasteFormat
            
            ' save and close the document
            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & FName
            
            .ActiveDocument.Save
            .ActiveDocument.Close
        End With
        FName = Dir
    Loop
    Set wrd = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    ' this routine opens a file dialog to allow the user to select which folder they want to load .docx files from
    
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    ' Finally, we add one last backslash to the path
    sItem = sItem & "\"
    
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Can anyone provide any insight as to why this works fine when run from within the document but not when opening a document from a folder?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with your using the Selection method versus Range method, coupled with the fact that you are creating a new instance of Word when it is already open because you are running the routine from another open document. When accessing more than one Word document at a time, it is a best practice to assign each open document its own Document object. That way when you are providing commands to Word, you are being explicit to what open document the command applies to.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers Rich - they are very much appreciated. I'll have more of a play and see if I can wrap my head around using range rather than selection.